# Strange Memory leak by new/delete in C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

Below is my question and code:

1. When code run to line 26, the memory obtained by this process does not return to OS?
2. But, if I delete line 16, the memory will be released correctly?

I know this is not the regular way to use so many small memory blocks, but I was very curious to know the reason.

I have run this program with `MALLOC_MMAP_MAX_=1000000 MALLOC_MMAP_THRESHOLD_=1024,` but nothing changed.

```
int i = 0;
std::cout << "waitting for input, you can check current memory" << std::endl;
std::cin >> i;
char** ptr = new char *[1000000];
std::map<int, char *> tMap;
for (unsigned long i = 0; i < 1000000; i ++)
{
    ptr[i] = new char[3000];
    tMap.insert(make_pair(i, ptr[i]));    //line 16
}
std::cout << "waitting for input, you can check current memory" << std::endl;
std::cin >> i;
for (unsigned long i = 0; i < 1000000; i ++)
{
    delete []ptr[i];
}
delete []ptr;
std::cout << "waitting for input, you can check current memory" << std::endl;
std::cin >> i;   //line 26
return 0;
```

here are more materials, And I have checked memory of tMap, less than 100M.

1、allocated memory and stop, check memory res:

[holds 2.9G memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jm8ZI.png)

2、deallocate memory and stop, check memory res:

[holds 2.9G memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHGBM.png)

Comment: How do you know?

Comment: Note that you have several variables around that are named `i`, that is dangerous and can lead to the compiler using another one that you thought it would. It probably works fine here,but it is a dangerous custom, avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1、when code run to line: 26, the memory obtained by this process does not return to OS ?

There's no guarantee any memory will be released by a C++ program *to the Operating System* just because it's `delete`d properly by the program.  In many C++ runtimes, dynamically allocated memory that's deleted will still be reserved for future use *by the same program*, and not released to the OS.  GCC/Linux is an example of an compiler/runtime-environment where *larger* allocations are usually done in shared memory segments that can be released to the Operating System before the program terminates, such that the OS or other programs can use them.

> 2、But, if I delete line: 16, the memory wile be released correctly ?

Line 16 doesn't make any difference to the later deletion/deallocation of the memory at line 22 (which may return it to the pool of dynamic memory that the application may later re-allocate, or actually release it to the OS as mentioned above).  It does involve more dynamic allocations for the `std::map` elements itself though.

Note that the `tMap` destructor does not itself `delete` or release the memory in any way.  To have memory automatically released - either by pointer-like variables or containers there-of - use *smart pointers* such as `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` (you can google them for information).

Comment: thanks for your answer, there are some key words may help a lot. The problem has been avoided by allocating big memory block instead of many small blocks. I post this question just for some details of C or C++ memory management.

Comment: Large pages are good.  Still: *"The problem has been avoided"* - was it actually a significant problem?  OSes tend to use *virtual memory* and configure some disk as *swap* - what happens is that memory content that your program has allocated but not used recently (and all deleted memory shouldn't be in use until new allocations puts it back in use) can be copied to disk, then the physical memory allocated for other programs.  Generally, it's only really a problem if you find your computer slowing down unacceptably, not just because the memory usage numbers look scary in `top` or `ps`....

Comment: you are right. Memory was still here. After delete, I try to allocate more memory but heap doesn’t grow any more. The most reasonable explain is that tMap separate memory blocks and make it hard to find a continuous block which larger than a specified size, then no memory returned to OS.  I will continue working on the details. Thanks a lot for the helping.

Answer (score 3):

C++ doesn't have garbage collection, so keeping an extra copy of a pointer doesn't stop the memory from being deallocated.

What happens after `delete[] ptr[i]` is that the map is full of dangling pointers that can no longer be used.

---

Another thought: What you might see as a memory leak is the fact that the `tMap` *also* allocates dynamic memory to store the inserted data. That memory will be released when the map goes out of scope, just after line 27.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have checked the memory of tMap, it's not a big deal comparing to 1 million  blocks of 3000 bytes. I have added two pics to show the memory status. Hope this will help to explain my question.